# MethodNotAllowedHttpException laravel-4

Tags: php, forms, exception, laravel, laravel-4

Form  :

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'user/create', 'files' => true)) }}
```

Route :

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

UserController.php

```
  class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        return 'hi11';
        //return View::make('home.index');
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return 'hi22';
        //return View::make('home.index');
    }

}
```

This code gives 
`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Comment: why you want to use create method? Resource controller was meant to ease your task by defining common curd functions.

Comment: This method I want to use insert user into data base.

Comment: for that only store method is created by resource controller

Answer (score 12):

I'd just like to add my own discovery along these lines... Maybe this will save someone else the head-scratching I just performed.

I too implemented the Route::resource mechanism. I couldn't figure out why my create was working but my update was not. It turns out you can't reuse the same form code exactly, the form that does an update must use the method PUT or PATCH. Why update couldn't be a POST is beyond me.

That is to say, the opening form tag for an update must look like this:

```
Form::model($thing, array(
    'method' => 'PUT', 
    'route' => array('things.update', $thing->id)
    )
```

Without specifying method => PUT, you get this not-helpful error.

Comment: Really an annoying "bug". Chrome Dev Tools and LiveHTTP Headers both failed to show the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because in your roures you use resourse controller, you can use only specific paths and actions, described in documentation http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers.

user/create ( UserController::create ) is where you need to show the form for adding a new user.

The actual storage of the user should be done in user/store i.e. your form must be send data to UserController::store() method.

In your case if you POST your form only to 'url' => 'user', this should automatically send data to the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

[Laravel 4 resources have named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers) - just use those:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'user.create', 'files' => true)) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I'm doing it, it might help someone, can be improved, but this would be main idea.

```
@if(isset($data))
    {{ Form::open(['route'=>['blog.update', isset($data) ? $data->slug : null],'method' => 'patch','role' => 'form', 'class' => 'blog-form form-horizontal']) }}
@else
    {{ Form::open(['route'=>'blog.store','role' => 'form', 'class' => 'blog-form form-horizontal']) }}
@endif
```