# Laravel resource routing - update throws "method not allowed" error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following resource route:

```
Route::resource('pools', 'PoolsController');
```

I also have an edit form which should post to the controller's "update" method, set up like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => ['pools.update', $pool['id']])) }}
```

When I submit the form, it opens www.domain.com/pools/6 (6 being `$pool['id']` above). However, instead of running the code in the `update()` method, it throws an error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Now, I've found Laravel's error reporting very unhelpful so far, and this is no exception. The error description is vague at best and does nothing to help me troubleshoot the issue.

I was under the impression that the update method should receive post data automatically when using resourceful routing. It has also worked in some examples before, using the same syntax.

So, can anyone tell me what might be going on here?

Comment: did you try passing  a method to the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MethodNotAllowedHttpException laravel-4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501653/methodnotallowedhttpexception-laravel-4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to run the code in the update method, you must spoof a PUT request. look here: [Form Method Spoofing](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: Right. Wrong request type. Thanks, will accept the answer. This may be a digression, but would it kill Laravel to just say "update method expects PUT data" instead of this generic error that could mean any number of different things?

Comment: it's actually pretty straight forward if you think about it. "method not allowed" would read "you haven't written code to handle this method" in laymen terms. also check [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)